# How to use an EventEmitter without @Output decorator?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In Angular 4 or 2, I want to emit an event from a component to a service which is not related to the component.

After emitting an action will occur and it will be handled in the service. Can someone give me a code example or any alternate solution for that?

**Note:** The service is not imported in that component and it should not call any of the service methods in the component but the service can call the component method.

Comment: Please share your component and service code.

Comment: Subscribe to the output event in the service

Comment: @CornelC can you please provide a sample code

Comment: your service knows about the component? I think you should update that design!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a create a new subject in the component and subscribe to that from the service. When you need to trigger the event you can call subject.next(). And the subcription in the service will be updated.

---

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

import {AppService} from './app.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    constructor() {
        AppComponent.getSubject().subscribe((response) => {
            this.doSomething(response);
        });
    }

    public doSomething(response): void {
        console.log('Event triggered', response);
    }
}
```

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private static subject = new Subject<string>();

  public static getSubject(): Observable<string> {
    return AppComponent.subject.asObservable();
  }

  public onClick(): void {
    AppComponent.subject.next('Test');
  }
}
```

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `<div>test component</div>`
})
export class TestComponent {
 constructor(private appService: AppService) {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the component `EventEmitter`in the service.

`myComponent.myEvent.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));`

Answer (score 0):

As @Ric comment above, think carefully why you want to access a component from a service (and not vice versa).

If you do need it for some reason and you don't want to fire events,
share a service between them, and subscribe to the changes. It is similar to angular's example, but in your case the parent is a service and not a component so all the other methods there aren't valid:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

If for some reason, this approach doesn't fit to your requirments - 
you can use callbacks (notice: i personally wouldn't use this approach).

See an example in here:
https://yakovfain.com/2016/10/31/angular-2-component-communication-with-events-vs-callbacks/

Good luck!